# Error when trying to pass a value to a parameter via a URL in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report in SSRS that has a drill-down report. I would like to have the action linking to the drill-down report open it in a new page.

I've used this expression as the action URL:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('server?ItemPath=%2fTimisoara%2fDrilldown%2fDrill01&ID=123', '_blank'))"
```

When trying to access the drill-down report I get the following error:

```
The ID parameter is missing value
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not constructing your URL properly. For starters the `server` bit should actually be the name of the server (or the IP address) and you need to properly construct the URL including the `http://`

You can then construct your URL like so:

`http://reportserver/ReportServer?/Path/To/Report/DrillDownReport&Param1=Value1&Param2=Value2`

I recommend reading the following MSDN pages:

- [URL Access (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153586.aspx)
- [Pass a Report Parameter Within a URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx)